# How to change the format of Date in Reactive Forms?

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap

I want to change the default date format in one of my fields in Reactive forms. It is appearing in the following format "16-03-1999" but I want to change in following format "March 16, 1999".

Below is the code for the same :

In type script file :

```
this.companyForms = this.fb.group({

})
```

I am adding the control dynamically in the form using the response of API

```
this.companyForms.addControl("EFFECTIVE_DATE", new FormGroup({
        'DEFAULT VALUE': new FormControl(null)
}))
```

In html file,

```
<form [formGroup]="companyForms">
   <div class="row pt-2" formGroupName="EFFECTIVE_DATE">
      <input type="date" class="form-control bg-light" name="DEFAULT VALUE" formControlName="DEFAULT VALUE" [value]="companyForms.get(['EFFECTIVE_DATE','DEFAULT VALUE'])| date:'longDate' ">
   </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to change the format of the date by using built in pipe longDate which is basically used to convert the date format into desired format. But after applying pipe also it is appearing in the same format 'dd-mm-yyyy'. I want it in "mmmm dd, yyyy" (June 26, 2019) format.

The date field still showing the default format in placeholder that is dd-mm-yyyy.

Any suggestions regarding this will be helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use Angular Material. It has this format (June 26, 2019)
html

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>datepicker</mat-label>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';
import * as _moment from 'moment';
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]
    },
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
}
```

demo in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9z6rhu?file=src/app/datepicker-formats-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you for response, Is there any way using bootstrap and angular as we are using the same in our application? The UI goes out if there is one field in angular material. Any suggestion regarding the same will be really helpful.

Comment: ng-bootstrap is more close to bootstrap than angular:https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

Answer (score 0):

`ng-bootstrap` provide a `ngb-datepicker` component. You can use it instead of the input. Here is the example from the official docs on how to format the date for this component: [custom date formatter](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples#adapter).

Code of the formatter itself:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomDateParserFormatter extends NgbDateParserFormatter {

  readonly DELIMITER = '/';

  parse(value: string): NgbDateStruct | null {
    if (value) {
      let date = value.split(this.DELIMITER);
      return {
        day : parseInt(date[0], 10),
        month : parseInt(date[1], 10),
        year : parseInt(date[2], 10)
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  format(date: NgbDateStruct | null): string {
    return date ? date.day + this.DELIMITER + date.month + this.DELIMITER + date.year : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I had tried this code earlier as well but it is not showing the output in long date format, I want the date something in this format (March 16, 2021)

Comment: To archive this you just need to change `format` and `parse` functions to accommodate this date format